# Android count time to close application

Tags: android, countdowntimer

i am trying to make count down timer to close application or prompt dialogbox after it expires.

Ex:

```
 if 0:30 sec ends application prompts dialogbox or close application
```

thank you have a nice day :)

Comment: And you have tried?  If the answer is nothing, then I have a few questions I haven't had the chance to attempt which I would love someone to do for me... why try when others will just do for you, right?

Comment: Very nice @Boldbayar .. please do make it and share with us :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can look for the CountDownTimer class

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/CountDownTimer.html

and you can close the application by either invoking

```
Activity.finish()
```

(if this is the last activity), or by killing the application (which is not a good idea), by either killing the Pid:

```
int pid = android.os.Process.myPid();
android.os.Process.killProcess(pid);
```

or by invoking

```
System.exit(0);
```

Comment: This "accepted" answer should not be followed.  Finishing or killing a process without understand why or how it should be done is bad form.